# Why is my JavaScript function not found only in debug?

Tags: javascript, debugging, blazor

I define this inside body section of index.html

```
    <script>
        function BlazorRegisterStorageEvent(component) {
            window.addEventListener("storage", async e => {
                await component.invokeMethodAsync("OnStorageUpdated", e.key);
            });
        }
    </script>
```

From Visual Studio 2019
If I start application without debugger (crtl-F5) it works fine.
If I start application WITH debugger I have this exception:

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find
> 'BlazorRegisterStorageEvent' ('BlazorRegisterStorageEvent' was
> undefined).

Thank you

Comment: instead of adding script tag in razor component create js file in wwwroot and link to project in _Host

Answer (score 0):

Sorry after cleaning chrome cache works fine also in debug.

Comment: put the script in the head section